# Объясните логику задачи в python: что делают отрицательные индексы в Питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x

Задача.

> Напишите программу, на вход которой подаётся список чисел одной строкой. Программа должна для каждого элемента этого списка вывести сумму двух его соседей. Для элементов списка, являющихся крайними, одним из соседей считается элемент, находящий на противоположном конце этого списка. Например, если на вход подаётся список "1 3 5 6 10", то на выход ожидается список "13 6 9 15 7" (без кавычек).
>
> Если на вход пришло только одно число, надо вывести его же.
>
> Вывод должен содержать одну строку с числами нового списка, разделёнными пробелом.
>
> Sample Input 1:
>
> 1 3 5 6 10
>
> Sample Output 1:
>
> 13 6 9 15 7
>
> Sample Input 2:
>
> 10
>
> Sample Output 2:
>
> 10

Решение нашёл на форуме.

```
x = input().split() #строка с числами разделенными пробелами на вход
if len(x) == 1:
    print(x[0])
elif len(x) > 1: # создаю новый список
y = [int(x[i-1])+int(x[i+1]) for i in range (-1, len(x)-1)]
for i in range (1, len(y)):
    print(y[i], end=' ') #вывожу значения со второго до последнего
print(y[0]) #вывожу первое значение
```

Вопрос, почему мы диапазон в range берём от -1, а не от 0 или 1. В чём логика такого действия?

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Почему не возникает ошибка при s\[0:len(s)\]?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/618165/23044)

Answer (score 4):

Отрицательный индекс в питоне это 'индекс от конца'. Сдвигая в минус вы формально избегаете деления по модулю в плюсе.
Лично я предпочел бы явное деление по модулю.

Comment: Не знаю, что такого страшного в отрицательном индексе? :) Если бы в списке `files` нужно было получить последний элемент через индексы, синтаксис `files[-1]` проще выглядит чем `files[len(files) - 1]`

Comment: @gil9red: произвольные последовательности (`collections.abc.Sequence`) [не обязаны поддерживать негативные индексы](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__), хотя [стандартные последовательности (строки, списки, итд) поддерживают негативные индексы](http://stackoverflow.com/a/509297/4279). Для наглядности, можно в ответ [диаграмму из вводного руководства добавить, которая иллюстрирует использование простых индексов](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations)

Comment: страшного ничего :)

Comment: простота и читаемость падает. от этого вопросты плодятся ненужные. спросите Оккама.

Comment: @kimstik почему вы думаете, что  `a[len(a)-1]` более читаемо чем `a[-1]` не такая уж и редкость когда последний элемент из последовательности достать хочется.

Answer (score 3):

Цикл будет идти от конца списка до количества введенных чисел - 1
В Python `a[-1] == a[len(a)-1]`  т.е. последний элемент списка. Это довольно удобно.

Comment: Это верно для встроенных последовательностей таких как списки, кортежи, строки в Питон, но [не все последовательности обязаны поддерживать отрицательные индексы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/589624/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%8a%d1%8f%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8-%d0%b2-python-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%9f%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5/589634#comment791169_589634)