# Выбрать каждое второе слово

Tags: python, список, текст, обработка-данных, range

Есть строка - `этот если способ вы плохо это подходит читаете для что-то шифрования пошло важных не сообщений так`
Нужно сделать выборку слов через одно слово, чтобы было читабельно.
По отдельности циклами могу выбрать. Если объединяю их, то результат получается похожий на таблицу умножения. Помогите пожалуйста, только начала изучать питон.
Должно получится так: если вы это читаете что-то пошло не так этот способ плохо подходит для шифрования важных сообщений

```
stroca = 'этот если способ вы плохо это подходит читаете для что-то шифрования пошло важных не сообщений так'

t=stroca.split()

print(t)
```

['этот', 'если', 'способ', 'вы', 'плохо', 'подходит', 'читаете', 'для', 'что-то', 'шифрования', 'пошло', 'не', 'сообщений', 'так']

```
for i in range(1,17,2):
        print (t[i])
```

если
вы
это
читаете
что-то
пошло
не
так

```
for j in range(0,16,2):
    print (t[j])
```

этот
способ
плохо
подходит
для
шифрования
важных
сообщений

Comment: В каком смысле объединяете?
укажите пример кода и ожидаемый результат в вопросе.

Comment: `l = [1,2,3,4,5], l[::2] --> [1,3,5]; l[1::2] --> [2,4]` Не нужны здесь никакие `range`

Comment: Должно получится так :  если вы это читаете что-то пошло не так этот способ плохо подходит для шифрования важных сообщений

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Должно получится так : `если вы это читаете что-то пошло не так этот способ плохо подходит для шифрования важных сообщений`

```
>>> words = 'этот если способ вы плохо это подходит читаете для что-то шифрования пошло важных не сообщений так'.split()
>>> print(*(words[1::2] + words[::2]))
если вы это читаете что-то пошло не так этот способ плохо подходит для шифрования важных сообщений
```

- [Что значит * (звёздочка) и ** двойная звёздочка в Питоне?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594651/23044)
- [Understanding Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/4279)
- [Больше чем вы когда-либо хотели знать о срезах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/618165/23044).

Answer (score 3):

Как я понял, у нас есть зашифрованная строка, полученная от соединения двух строк и в вопросе уже был приведен алгоритм разделения. Дополнительно, нужно сделать функцию объединения:

```
def my_split(text):
    items = text.split()
    return items[::2], items[1::2]


def my_merge(items_1, items_2):
    return ' '.join(items_2 + items_1)


text = 'этот если способ вы плохо это подходит читаете для что-то шифрования пошло важных не сообщений так'
print(text)

items_1, items_2 = my_split(text)
print(items_1)
print(items_2)
print()

new_text = my_merge(items_1, items_2)
print(new_text)
print(new_text == 'если вы это читаете что-то пошло не так этот способ плохо подходит для шифрования важных сообщений')
```

Консоль:

```
этот если способ вы плохо это подходит читаете для что-то шифрования пошло важных не сообщений так
['этот', 'способ', 'плохо', 'подходит', 'для', 'шифрования', 'важных', 'сообщений']
['если', 'вы', 'это', 'читаете', 'что-то', 'пошло', 'не', 'так']

если вы это читаете что-то пошло не так этот способ плохо подходит для шифрования важных сообщений
True
```

---

**UPD.** Обновил ответ в связи с уточнением вопроса

Comment: `items_1 = items[::2]` Ну гораздо же питоничнее))

Comment: точно, а я пишу и думаю что-то многословно выходит :)

Comment: Спасибо буду пробовать делать

Comment: @Анна, отметьте тогда ответ как правильный :)

Answer (score 0):

немного поздновато с ответом, но все же..

```
    a = ' этот если способ вы плохо это подходит читаете для что-то шифрования пошло важных не сообщений так'
    a = a.split()
    print(a[:-1:2])
    print(a[1::2])
```