# Как напечатать в строку список?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, список

```
text = ("этот если способ вы плохо это подходит читаете для что-то шифрования пошло важных не сообщений так")
goodtext = text.split(' ')
textstring = ' '.join(goodtext)
x = 0
y = 0
lengthtext = len(goodtext)
for x in range(0, lengthtext, 2):
    print(goodtext[x])
```

как напечатать каждое второе слово в тексте не в столбик, а в строку?

Comment: `print(goodtext[x], end="")`

Comment: Спасибо, большое всем!!!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/781246/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE/781269?noredirect=1#comment1225317_781269

Answer (score 1):

```
In [44]: for i in text.split()[::2]:
    ...:     print(i, end=' ')
```

Или так:

```
In [45]: print(*text.split()[::2], end=' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно при помощи `list` сделать добавление каждого второго слова
Пример:

```
text = ("этот если способ вы плохо это подходит читаете для что-то шифрования пошло важных не сообщений так")
goodtext = text.split(' ')
textstring = ' '.join(goodtext)
a = []
lengthtext = len(goodtext)
for x in range(0, lengthtext, 2):
    a.append(goodtext[x])    
print(*a)
# этот способ плохо подходит для шифрования важных сообщений
```

---

Или при помощи `end=' '`

Пример:

```
text = ("этот если способ вы плохо это подходит читаете для что-то шифрования пошло важных не сообщений так")
goodtext = text.split(' ')
textstring = ' '.join(goodtext)
lengthtext = len(goodtext)
for u in range(0, lengthtext, 2):
    print(goodtext[u], end=" ")
# этот способ плохо подходит для шифрования важных сообщений
```

Comment: Спасибо, большое всем!!!