# dict.get для списков. Можно ли как-то безболезненно получить значение из списка в python?

Tags: python-3.x

Для словарей есть метод get который не кидает исключений и позволят красиво в одну строку писать. Есть ли такой же способ для списков?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы получить значение из списка `lst`, зная его индекс `i` в Питоне:

```
value = lst[i]
```

Если индекс может выходить за пределы списка. К примеру, если аргумент командной строки не обязателен (`Usage: program [<value>]`) и принимает `default` значение, если явно не указан:

```
value = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else default
```

Иногда можно исключения использовать. К примеру, если команда ожидает целое число в качестве аргумента командной строки:

```
try:
    n = int(sys.argv[1])
except (IndexError, ValueError):
    sys.exit(__doc__)
```

`IndexError` обрабатывает случай когда аргумент вообще не задан. `ValueError` указывает, что не целое число было передано. `sys.exit(__doc__)` выходит и печатает docstring (которая `Usage: program <n>` содержит) в случае неверного вызова команды.

Добавление `list.get` было отклонено [dict get() function equivalent for lists](https://bugs.python.org/issue32979), с обоснованием, что [не достаточно часто встречается и скрывает ошибки индексирования](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2017-February/044848.html). О частоте использования это не похоже на правду, что хотя бы свидетельствуется несколькими популярными Stack Overflow вопросами (и из личного опыта: я наблюдаю в своём коде как вариант с `if len(sys.argv) > 1` так и вариант c IndexError так и другие варианты, которые выражают `list.get()` идею). Эти случаи были не слишком частыми, чтобы вспомогательную функцию определять, но если в вашем коде вам часто это нужно, то просто оберните try/except в функцию и вызывайте `get(lst, i, default)`.

В разных обстоятельствах разные подходы могут быть более подходящие. К примеру, чтобы [получить первый элемент в списке или `None`, если список пустой](https://stackoverflow.com/q/363944/4279):

```
value = next(iter(lst), None)
```

Срезы уходящие за границы возвращают пустые списки в Питоне: `lst[i:i+1]`. [Почему не возникает ошибка при `s[0:len(s)]`?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/618165/23044)

Мне не нравятся однострочники типа:

```
value = next(iter(lst[i:i+1]), default)
```

или

```
[value] = lst[i:i+1] or [default]
```

YMMV. См. дополнительные варианты: [How to get the nth element of a python list or a default if not available](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2492087/4279).

Answer (score 2):

Вот [по этой ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125619/why-doesnt-list-have-safe-get-method-like-dictionary) народ говорит, что такого метода нет, и проводит примеры, как такой метод написать самому:

```
def safe_list_get (l, idx, default):
  try:
    return l[idx]
  except IndexError:
    return default
```