# Почему выводит False? В строке "a" содержится же "Привет". Может я что-то неправильно пишу?

Tags: python, строки

```
a = "Привет"
if a[0:5] == "Привет":
   print(True)
else:
   print(False)
```

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Почему не возникает ошибка при s\[0:len(s)\]?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/618165/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы неправильно оперируете срезами. В `a[0:5]` содержится "Приве". А вот `a[0:6]` уже "Привет".

Почитайте https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/indeksy-i-srezy.html

На самом деле тут, конечно, никакие срезы не нужны вовсе

```
a = "Привет"                                                                    
print(a == "Привет")
```

Answer (score -1):

Потому как вот так:

```
a = "Привет"
if a == "Привет":
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)

True
```

или так

```
a = "Привет"
if a [0:5]== "Приве":
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)

True
```